# Спонтанное пробуждение компьютера

Tags: windows

Сколько не сидел на windows всегда у меня была эта проблема: комп сам по себе пробуждается из спящего режима и я ничего не могу с этим поделать. Перепробовал все что нашел в гугле: отключение таймеров пробуждения, отключение возможности пробуждения отдельно у каждого устройства в диспетчере устройств - ничего не помогает. Я не люблю полностью выключать комп и почти никогда это не делаю, но когда он посреди ночи просыпается и начинает гудеть - это не дает заснуть (он стоит рядом с моим диваном). Помогите! Как сделать чтобы мой комп перестала мучить бессонница? :D

P.S. Сейчас windows 10, но эта же проблема была и на windows 7. А вот к примеру когда я ставил линукс - ничего подобного не наблюдалось.

Answer (score 3):

Ещё варианты:

1) WakeOnLan (или нечто подобное) в BIOS*;

2) Если клавиатура с кнопками управления питанием (выключение, спящий и т.п.), возможно поможет чистка клавиатуры (НЕ водой! Мембраны лучше сухой мягкой тряпочкой... Механических с такими кнопульками не видывал, да и чистка механики в таких случаях не поможет).

.* -  Внимание: если с BIOS-ом ранее не работали, то следует сперва как следует покурить тему :) И быть предельно осторожными, не нажимать "всё подряд", подходить с умом :)

Comment: Попробую как-нибудь эту опцию поискать. А насчет клавиатуры не понял при чем тут она? Комп просыпается не от нажатия на клавишу, а сам по себе. И потом я уже сказал что я отключал в диспетчере устройств возможность пробуждения в том числе и для клавиатуры.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала посмотрите планировщик заданий (`Панель управления->Администрирование->Планировщик заданий`), какие там задачи стоят и в какое время выполняются. Скорее всего у какой-то программы идет обновление, которое и выводит компьютер из спящего режима. Определите программу - дальше уже решайте что с ней делать (в некоторых достаточно просто снять пункт автоматического обновления).

> отключение таймеров пробуждения, отключение возможности пробуждения отдельно у каждого устройства в диспетчере устройств

Это может не помочь, если идет обновление программы, которая имеет расширенный доступ к ядру операционной системы.

Comment: Тут довольно приличное количество тасков. Мне что просто начать удалять все подряд оттуда? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swdxt.png

Comment: @DarkByte попробуйте определить ориентировочное время, когда компьютер выходит из спящего режима и посмотрите по времени запуска какие именно таски выполнялись в это время, далее поочередно отрубаем их до устранения проблемы.